# Can I use a German XBOX360 in Pakistan?

Tags: xbox-360

Can I use a XBOX 360 that was bought in Germany by my Father here in Pakistan?

Comment: What matters is that games must respect the format the console is prepared for. If your 360 uses PAL format, games must be PAL, the same with NTSC.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Just make sure the games are the same format as the 360. For example ntsc/pal there are a few more I forget what they are though.